# Rails subquery without SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` model that has many `Post`.

I want to get, on a single query, a list of users IDs, ordered by name, and include the ID of their last post.

Is there a way to do this using the ActiveRecord API instead of a SQL query like the following?

```
SELECT users.id, 
    (SELECT id FROM posts 
     WHERE user_id = users.id 
     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_post_id
FROM users
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the query generator:

```
User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').order('users.id').pluck(:id, 'MAX(posts.id)')
```

There's a lot of options on the relationship you can use to get data out of it. `pluck` is handy for getting values independent of models.

**Update:** To get models instead:

```
User.joins(:posts).group('users.id').order('users.id').select('users.*', 'MAX(posts.id) AS max_post_id')
```

That will create a field called `max_post_id` which works as any other attribute.

Comment: thanks, works great! is there a way to return the users as ActiveRecord objects and still have access to the last post id? (even if I have to select all User columns)

Comment: Updated the answer with a way of getting models.